# Summation notation

Tags: notation, sum

I am reading a statistics book which says:

" If  $ X \sim N ( \mu, \sigma^2)$, it is verified that:

$  \sum_{i=1}^{n}X \sim N ( n\mu, n\sigma^2) $

My doubt is if it should have been written as $  \sum_{i=1}^{n}Xi $  or, considering that $X$ is a random variable, this is already implicit.

Comment: Yes, that's sloppy notation.

Comment: @abstrusiosity with a little context, I guess you can convert it to an answer.

Comment: @gunes Ok, I made it an answer.

Comment: Read literally, the result is false.  According to standard mathematical notation, the sum is meaningful and $\sum_{i=1}^n X = nX \sim N(n\mu,n^2\sigma^2).$ The book must have established a context in which it was understood that "$X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$" means there is a sequence $(X_i)$ of *iid* variables with the given distribution.  *In that context,* the summation can be correctly understood.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that it should be written as $\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i$.

[Sigma notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation#Capital-sigma_notation) requires an index variable and the index variable needs to be indicated in the summand.  Sometimes the index is omitted if the context is clear, like $ \sum X $, but if it appears in the Sigma then it needs to be in the $X$, too.